# Is there a way to use Google's advanced search parameters without triggering the CAPTCHA test?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, recaptcha

When using Googles advanced search operators, I only ever get about three or four tries before I start getting harassed by these perpetual reCAPTCHA turing tests:

[image]

---

Yes, I'm human. No, I'm not a robot. No I'm not doing anything suspicious. Yes, I can identify street signs and traffic lights and storefronts and motorcycles. Is there some way around this?

I know it's there for a reason, but so are the advanced parameters, right? It's a search engine. Sometimes you have to really *search* to get the results you're looking for. I'm using these features as they were intended; to search smarter; to reduce the number of false positives. The internet is too big to be casting too wide a net all the time.

---

Here's a real quick example. 
Say you want to which Spider-Man movies are showing on Netflix. But not the ones with Tobey Maguire. And only in France. Or Italy. You could form a search query utilizing the following operator/parameter combinations:

- ```
  site:"netflix.com"
  ```
- ```
  intitle:"spider-man"
  ```
- ```
  inurl:"/(fr|it)/title/"
  ```
- ```
  -"tobey maguire"
  ```

Comment: I guess not. capatcha is safety future against bots which is backfiring on actual more advanced humans who are able to use search operators.

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER Therein lies the problem.